# Efficient way to draw 3! ( 6 times) three shapes in C

Tags: c, ubuntu, drawing, ascii, shapes

I want to draw all the combinations (3! = 6) of 3 shapes , in one row : empty cell , `X` , or a rectangle .

The current code :

For empty cell :

```
void drawEmptyCell()
{

    printf("||||||||||||||||||||||||||\n");
    printf("|                        |\n");
    printf("|                        |\n");
    printf("|                        |\n");
    printf("|                        |\n");
    printf("|                        |\n");
    printf("|                        |\n");
    printf("|                        |\n");
    printf("|                        |\n");
    printf("|                        |\n");
    printf("|                        |\n");
    printf("||||||||||||||||||||||||||\n");

}
```

For a cell with a rectangle :

```
void drawCellWithRectangle()
{

    printf("||||||||||||||||||||||||||\n");
    printf("|                        |\n");
    printf("|                        |\n");
    printf("|     **************     |\n");
    printf("|     *            *     |\n");
    printf("|     *            *     |\n");
    printf("|     *            *     |\n");
    printf("|     *            *     |\n");
    printf("|     *            *     |\n");
    printf("|     **************     |\n");
    printf("|                        |\n");
    printf("|                        |\n");
    printf("||||||||||||||||||||||||||\n");

}
```

And for a cell with `X` :

```
void drawCellWithX()
{

    printf("||||||||||||||||||||||||||\n");
    printf("|                        |\n");
    printf("|   *               *    |\n");
    printf("|     *           *      |\n");
    printf("|       *       *        |\n");
    printf("|         *   *          |\n");
    printf("|           *            |\n");
    printf("|         *   *          |\n");
    printf("|       *       *        |\n");
    printf("|     *           *      |\n");
    printf("|   *               *    |\n");
    printf("|                        |\n");
    printf("||||||||||||||||||||||||||\n");

}
```

I can use the brute force way and take all 6 options , for example :

```
void drawOption1()
{
    // empty , rectangle , x

    printf("||||||||||||||||||||||||||");printf("||||||||||||||||||||||||||");printf("||||||||||||||||||||||||||\n");
    printf("|                        |");printf("|                        |");printf("|                        |\n");
    printf("|                        |");printf("|                        |");printf("|   *               *    |\n");
    printf("|                        |");printf("|     **************     |");printf("|     *           *      |\n");
    printf("|                        |");printf("|     *            *     |");printf("|       *       *        |\n");
    printf("|                        |");printf("|     *            *     |");printf("|         *   *          |\n");
    printf("|                        |");printf("|     *            *     |");printf("|           *            |\n");
    printf("|                        |");printf("|     *            *     |");printf("|         *   *          |\n");
    printf("|                        |");printf("|     *            *     |");printf("|       *       *        |\n");
    printf("|                        |");printf("|     **************     |");printf("|     *           *      |\n");
    printf("|                        |");printf("|                        |");printf("|   *               *    |\n");
    printf("|                        |");printf("|                        |");printf("|                        |\n");
    printf("||||||||||||||||||||||||||");printf("||||||||||||||||||||||||||");printf("||||||||||||||||||||||||||\n");

}
```

But I'm looking for something else , without a brute force all the way .

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A good approach will be to put the shapes into a string array.
Then a appropriate algorithm will draw them

Something like the following will do the job. 
Hope you get the idea

```
char* x[] = { 
  "||||||||||||||||||||||||||",
  "|                        |",
  "|   *               *    |",
  "|     *           *      |",
  "|       *       *        |",
  "|         *   *          |",
  "|           *            |",
  "|         *   *          |",
  "|       *       *        |",
  "|     *           *      |",
  "|   *               *    |",
  "|                        |",
  "||||||||||||||||||||||||||"};
char* o[] ..
char* empty[] ..
..
output (" XO");
..
void output (const char* pOut) {
  // assert (sizeof(x) == sizeof(o));
  // assert (sizeof(x) == sizeof(empty));
  int i, j;

  for (i = 0; i < sizeof(o) / sizeof(o[0]); i ++) {
    const char* c = pOut;
    while (*c != 0) {
      switch (*c ++) {
      case 'X':
       printf (x[i]); break; 
      case 'O':
       printf (o[i]); break;
      default: 
         printf (empty[i]); break;
      }
    }
    printf ("\n");
  }
}
```

Obviously x,o, empty are required to hold the same number of line.

now in C, no compiled yet, so it may have errors

Answer (score 3):

You can use [gotoxy(x,y);](http://www.programmingsimplified.com/c/conio.h/gotoxy) and `printf();` in a `for-loop`.

Comment: `gotoxy` is non-standard and the OP hasn't specified a compiler or platform. ncurses would be a much more general and portable solution.

Comment: Basically, you have a point but using `gotoxy();` with proper algorithm is like manipulating a matrix with the screen as the grid. That alone could be very helpful.

Comment: @Christian Mark: I'm using Ubuntu platform , hence I can't use the `#include <windows.h>` header

Comment: Thank you for mentioning that but I think its to late.